# Suggestions to follow while tutoring online a French student who wants to improve his speaking listening skills in English?

Tags: spoken-english, listening, french

I'll be tutoring online a french student who I think has at least an advanced intermediate level in all parts of English, and wants to improve his speaking and listening skills, specially following fast spoken English. Now I'm not a licensed English teacher. Are there any specific suggestions I could follow that'd be more beneficial for the French student in particular? How can I make it interesting? What pitfalls should I watch out for?

What're the general mistakes the French make while speaking English?

Comment: What is your English level? Native or fluent?

Comment: Listen to the musucal Hamilton?  Fun but really fast lines.

Comment: Listening and repeating John Mulaney jokes. Fun but challenging.

Comment: @Mari-LouA both pieces of really good advice — especially jokes or watching comedians — but it’s hard for even a native English speaker in some sections to pick up on all of the words in *Hamilton*, and I imagine it would be doubly hard for a non-native speaker.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions on "improving one's English" are off-topic. Also, the other requests are too broad. See the [help center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for on-topic questions.

Comment: @StephenS Bilingual/native with a C2 certificate, with lots of years in the States.